# How can I set up a bluetooth mouse without using a mouse?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Mac Mini with an Apple Magic Mouse bluetooth mouse. In order to set up a bluetooth mouse, though, it looks like you have to use a mouse. Doesn't that completely defeat the purpose? Is there a way I can set up my bluetooth mouse using the commandline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure if you can do it in a terminal, but with my iMac I used tabbing instead.

Tabbing is just that, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> all the time until you highlight the button that you want to "click", of course, using <kbd>Space</kbd>.

I would recommend you to get an USB Mouse, anyway here you have some steps:

1. Boot ubuntu. Open the Dash pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> (Command). Now type **Bluetooth** and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
2. Wait until the settings panel appears. Now press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the + icon looks highlighted. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>.
3. Find your Magic Mouse, and select it tabbing. Do tabbing again to the **Next** button.
4. Now wait until the mouse is correctly linked.

Happy *ubunting* on your Mac Mini! :)

Answer (score 3):

#### No need for 'tabbing' around

Here's how to do pair input devices using the command line. I assume you put your device in discovery mode first, of course.

1. Determine the Bluetooth adapter identifier (e.g. `hci0`)

   ```
   hcitool dev
   ```
2. Scan for devices

   ```
   hcitool scan
   ```
3. Locate the device you want to pair up with. Copy the hardware address on the clipboard.
4. Try to connect (replace `hci0` with your actual Bluetooth adapter identifier as well as the Bluetooth device address to pair with):

   ```
   sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
   ```

   - For keyboards only: In case the above step returns something like `DisplayPasskey (/org/bluez/537/hci0/..., 123456)`, then the last part is the PIN number to enter (here `123456`). Refer to the manual of your Bluetooth input device how to do this.

   It should output something like `New device (/org/bluez/...`
5. Mark the device as trusted, system-wide:

   ```
   sudo bluez-test-device trusted aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff yes
   ```
6. If it doesn't work yet at this point already, try this:

   ```
   sudo bluez-test-input connect aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
   ```

Further idea: Create a wrapper script to make it a single command for your machine.

#### Reverting actions

Also useful if you get errors due to other applications having fiddled with Bluetooth.

```
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff repair
```

#### References

Used this page as the main reference for the steps above:

- [Ubuntu 12.04 persistent bluetooth pairing](http://devasive.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html)